# Row output is empty

Tags: php, db2, row

Row output is empty, but i has exact the amount of rows i have in my database. 
How can i get it to print my p510key in rows? i've tried to do like `.$row[p510key]`  and also tried to `.$pgrupp[p510KEY]`
How does this row work? what did i miss out on?

```
 <?php            
        $dbhost = '***';
        $dbuser = '****';
        $dbpass = '****';

    $conn = db2_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    $pgrupp = db2_result($queryexe, 'P510KEY');
    $query = "SELECT P510KEY FROM P510F";
    $result = db2_exec($conn, $query) or die(mysql_error()."[".$query."]");
?>

<select name="categories">
    <?php 
    while ($row = db2_fetch_row($result))
    {
        echo "<option value='".$row[0]."'>'".$row[1]."'</option>";
    }
    ?>        
</select>
```

Comment: Try printing out the whole $row to see if anything gets printed out.

Comment: do you have anything in the table?

Answer (score 0):

try to modify your code like this

```
while ($row = db2_fetch_row($result))
{
    echo "<option value='".$row['P510KEY']."'>'".$row['P510KEY']."'</option>";
}
```

you cant do $row[1], you have only one column in your select query